# what i need to consider when building phar file from php application use php framework like laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php, phar

I am php developer use laravel-4 as framework for building web applications , in the last few days I wanted to create phar file from my web application created on laravel framework .

I searched in the web for tools build php archive files (.phar) and I found 
[PHP box](https://github.com/kherge/php-box) , this tool is very good and use json configuration file for building the phar files but i could not use it for creating my phar files because there is many considerations when creating phar file from a web application use a framework like laravel . my questions are :

laravel use composer autoloader as auto loading mechanism

1-  how to handle composer auto loading mechanism ?

2-  how to handle the framework bootstrapping process ?  'like laravel'

3- what i need to make the browser read  my  index page from inside the phar file ?

4- how to use framework command line tools from the phar file ?  'like laravel-artisan'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use composer.json in your application and require box there.
When your application runs on laravel, you know that your bootstrap works and would also work inside a phar.

I believe Box brings a lot of the composer autloading stuff itself, so you won't run into trouble with it. I think the class_map gets included automatically.

One thing to consider is, that configuration details must be passed in!

In general, you need to "forward" to your application, which is inside the phar, like so:

```
<?php
require_once "phar://myapp.phar/frontcontroller.php"; // maybe index.php
$config = array('dsn' => 'database-config');
Application::run($config);
```

Also accessing a PHAR in a PHAR is a problem!

You can't access a PHAR packaged in a PHAR directly.
Firstly you need to extract the packaged PHAR, secondly do the forwarding call and pass the CLI commands along. Problem solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13537329/1163786

**Full Example**

**box.json.dist**

```
{
  "main": "bootstrap.php",
  "output": "application.phar",
  "compactors": ["Herrera\\Box\\Compactor\\Composer"],
  "chmod": "0755",
  "directories": ["src/"],
  "stub": true
}
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //<-- this is autoload.php generated by Composer

use MyApp\Application;

$config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__.'/config.ini');

$app = new Application();
$app->run($config);
```

Comment: Some people build application.phar and place their framework.phar inside it, so i just wanted to make you aware that it might get a bit messy.

Comment: first ** thank you very much for answering me ** .
but I am not trying to accessing phar in phar .
I just need to build phar file from my web application with it dependences (the vendor directory) .
how to call `composer/autoload.php` file from inside the phar file

Comment: updated my answer accordingly. please see bootstrap.php, where i'm including the composer autoloader...

Comment: this is the best answer for this question .
but well not work for laravel because it is very complicated framework in it bootstrap and run process .